# how to enable feature enable_multiple_brands in branding api of one login

Tags: onelogin, branding

I am getting this error while creating account brand in OneLogin I am attaching the screenshot below [branding api error message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ia3Hz.png)

Answer (score 0):

This must be enabled by your OneLogin account manager. It must be a production, paid account and not a developer or trial account. If you do not have an account large enough for an account manager, you can reach out to:
sales@onelogin.com (or olsm@quest.com) and CC license@quest.com